# How do I do operations on an inherited base constructor in C#?

Tags: c#

Example

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA(string someString){}
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public ClassB(string someString):base(someString.ToLower()){}
}
```

I call the inherited ClassB constructor.  I pass in a null.  ToLower() throws an exception on a null.  I want to check for a null before that happens.  How can I do this?

Comment: And what do you want to do if the string is null?

Comment: More then likely pass the null to ClassA.  Other options include passing a String.Empty or some "default" string.

Comment: @danmine: that is fairly easy to overcome; pick the one as accepted answer and upvote the others; it's only a 5 reputation difference.

Comment: In my opinion, I think that would be a disservice to the other answers.  People spend a lot of effort thinking of answers to the question.  The green check mark attracts puts that particular answer on top and it also attracts people's vision even though the other answers could be equally valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple. Using [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
public ClassB(string someString) : 
    base((someString ?? "").ToLower())
{
}
```

Or using [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(VS.80).aspx)

```
public ClassB(string someString) : 
    base(someString == null ? "" : someString.ToLower())
{
}
```

Better yet, I'd suggest you to add a no-arg constuctor to `ClassB`, which will call `base(string.Empty)`.

Comment: I always forget about this ?? operator, thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: Wow, here I was trying to make something simple hard!  I didn't even know about the ??

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
base(someString == null ? string.Empty : someString.ToLower())
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA(string someString) { }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public ClassB(string someString) : base(someString == null  ? "" :  someString.ToLower()) { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have already gotten answers on your question, but I just want to add that the approach strikes me as a bit odd. Is it really the caller's responsibility to make sure that the input is in lower case? I would definitely make this check and conversion in the base class constructor instead:

```
class Base
{
    private string _someString;
    public Base(string someString)
    {
        _someString = someString != null ? someString.ToLower() : null;
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(string someString) : base(someString) { }
}
```

This way the base class is not dependent on how the derived class chooses to pass the argument.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if `someString` is null in your base class and act accordingly, otherwise you can do something like this, but I think its very unreadable.

```
public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public ClassB(string someString):base((String.IsNullOrEmpty(someString)) ? String.Empty : someString.ToLower()){}
}
```